# Custom Activity as InputType for EditText

Tags: android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have an activity with custom code (calculator). I want to call it as input type when EditText is clicked on. Is there a way to replace existing input type with this activity and what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create custom keyboard and attach the desired functionality to it.